# Ballerina Native Client Connectors

Tags: ballerina

I see some AWSEC2 basic controls are being developed for Ballerina. I would like to create a set of controls for Oracle OCI. Is the native client connectors the path to do so? Or is there another extension approach?

Following the thread on AWSEC2, a base set would be something like the following:

```
Images
    CreateImage
    ListImages

PublicIP Addresses
    CreatePublicIP
    UpdatePublicIP

Instances
    ListInstances
    GetInstance
    LaunchInstance
    InstanceAction:stop
    InstanceAction:start
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a set of controls for Oracle OCI by extending ballerina language abstractions.(Eg. Endpoint). Basically you need to extend client endpoint with Oracle Cloud services APIs. Documentation of creating a sample endpoint can be found [here](https://ballerina.io/learn/how-to-extend-ballerina/).

You can refer these [existing connectors](https://github.com/wso2-ballerina) which is implemented by extending the behavior of ballerina and package.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implement this in Ballerina itself by using the [OCI Rest API](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/usingapi.htm). (You can use Ballerina HTTP package for this) 
You could refer such existing packages written in Ballerina such as [amazon s3 package](https://github.com/wso2-ballerina/package-amazons3).